# Convert ogg file to mp3 file in node

Tags: node.js, mp3, ogg

Does someone know how to convert ogg files to mp3 files in node? Some free libarary or snippet to achieve that?

---

Comment: Spawn a ffmpeg child process from node.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for your answer! I have the following code:

 `const inputFile = createReadStream("temp.ogg");
  const outputPath = "temp.mp3";
  const outputStream = createWriteStream(outputPath);
  const convertion = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    "-i",
    "pipe:0",
    "-f",
    "mp3",
    "pipe:1",
  ]);
  inputFile.pipe(convertion.stdin);
  convertion.stdout.pipe(outputStream);`

But I'm getting an error on Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit do you know why?

Comment: @AlbertGomárizSancha Take a look at stderr and see if you can figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 5):

Install the `fluent-ffmpeg` and `@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg` using npm.

Use these commands for installation

npm i @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg

npm i fluent-ffmpeg

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
  , fs = require('fs')
  ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
var outStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.mp3');

ffmpeg()
  .input('./input.ogg')
  .audioQuality(96)
  .toFormat("mp3")
  .on('error', error => console.log(`Encoding Error: ${error.message}`))
  .on('exit', () => console.log('Audio recorder exited'))
  .on('close', () => console.log('Audio recorder closed'))
  .on('end', () => console.log('Audio Transcoding succeeded !'))
  .pipe(outStream, { end: true });
```